# Excel VBA Append Cell to a different sheet Based on a column in same row saying "Yes"

Tags: excel, vba, list, append

Ok I have tried and failed here, but I have 2 sheets in the same workbook.

Sheet "AF" and sheet "CurrentList".

If Column S in the sheet "CurrentList" says "Yes" I want to append Column R in that same row to the bottom of a running list in Sheet "AF".  Sheet AF may already have 50000 values in there, so it has to append to the very bottom of the list.

I started trying to break apart some other code but it's throwing tons of errors, so not sure this is the approach:

```
Sub AddData()
 Dim wsDA As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet, lastRDA As Long, lastRD As Long
 Dim arrDA As Variant, rngDel As Range, arrD As Variant, arrCopy As Variant
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
 
 Set wsDA = Worksheets("CurrentList")
 Set wsD = Worksheets("AF")
 lastRDA = wsDA.Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 lastRD = wsD.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 'I got completely lost at this point..
 arrDA = wsDA.Range("R:" & lastRDA).Value
 arrD = wsD.Range("A1" & lastRDA).Value
 
 ReDim arrCopy(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(arrDA))
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrDA)
    If arrDA(i, 10) = "Yes" Then
        k = k + 1: arrCopy(1, k) = arrDA(i, 1): arrCopy(2, k) = arrDA(i, 2)
        arrCopy(2, k) = arrDA(i, 3)
    End
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you got so far.

Comment: Yeah I just posted what is likely way off in original post.

Comment: Are you going to write the result to the column or to the row below the last used cell?

Comment: So it’s an append , column A in AF Sheet will have a continuously growing list throughout the month.  Any of the rows that have “Yes” in column S of “CurrenrSheet”, I simply want to paste column R of that same row to the bottom of the list in the AF sheet.

Answer (score 0):

**VBA Lookup**

**Tips**

- Don't forget about the workbook.
- Use descriptive variable names.
- Add some comments. Not as much as I did, but comment each section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddData()
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Lookup and Result Arrays.
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    ' Define Source Worksheet.
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Set src = wb.Worksheets("CurrentList")
    ' Define Source Last Row.
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Define Source Lookup Column Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = src.Range("S1").Resize(LastRow)
    ' Write values from Source Lookup Column Range to Lookup Array.
    Dim Lookup As Variant
    Lookup = rng.Value
    ' Define Source Result Column Range.
    Set rng = src.Range("R1").Resize(LastRow)
    ' Write values from Source Result Column Range to Result Array.
    Dim Result As Variant
    Result = rng.Value
    
    ' Status: We have two arrays of the same size. We are going
    '         look for "Yes" in Lookup Array and write the corresponding
    '         value in Result Array to Result Array, yes, to the same array.
    '         We cannot get more matching results, so there will be no overflow.
    '         We will count the number of matches (MatchCount) to later know
    '         how many values to write to the Destination Range.
    
    ' Write values from Lookup and Result Arrays to Result Array (No typo).
    
    Dim LookupValue As Variant ' Current Lookup Value: the value
                               ' in the current element of Lookup Array
    Dim i As Long              ' Lookup/Result Array Counter (same size)
    Dim MatchCount As Long     ' Match Counter
    
    ' Iterate rows (values) in Lookup Array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(Lookup)
        ' Write value of current element in Lookup Array to Lookup Value
        LookupValue = Lookup(i, 1)
        ' Check if Lookup Value is not an error value.
        If Not IsError(LookupValue) Then
            ' Check if Lookup Value is equal to the Criteria ("Yes").
            If LookupValue = "Yes" Then
                ' Increase the Match Count.
                MatchCount = MatchCount + 1
                ' Write value of current element in Result Array
                ' to the position determined by Match Count to itself.
                Result(MatchCount, 1) = Result(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ' Validate Match Count.
    If MatchCount = 0 Then ' No match was found.
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Write values from Result Array to Destination Range.
        
    ' Define Destination Worksheet.
    Dim dst As Worksheet
    Set dst = wb.Worksheets("AF")
    ' Define Destination First Cell, the cell after the last non-empty cell.
    Set rng = dst.Cells(dst.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    ' Define Destination Range.
    ' Note that you can resize only an array's last dimension which in our case
    ' is columns, and not rows. So we resize the resulting
    ' Destination range only to the size of Match Count, not to
    ' the size of 'UBound(Result, 1)'.
    Set rng = rng.Resize(MatchCount)
    ' Write values from Result Array to Destination Range.
    rng.Value = Result
        
    ' Inform user.
    
    MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much.  For some odd reason though, I have to run this twice for it do what it needs to do.  The line that it gets caught on is:      LastRow = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row     --- Also, perhaps a dumb question, but the option explicit at the very top prompts to ask which of the modules to run.  It works, but just 2 little quirks I'm hoping to better understand why it does that.  I will mark as answered shortly , as this is fantastic.  Also that is awesome how you added in the message box, I can utilize that for my other steps as well!

Comment: You have to click into any procedure (Sub) to run it without the prompt. `Option Explicit` is outside of any procedure, in the declaration area of the module. It's not a dumb question, it happened to me a million times and is still happening. Not sure what's with the `LastRow` issue though. Can you share the exact text of the error occurring or describe what is happening in more detail?

Comment: So it's not an error, it's showing the red dot , which I believe is simply a breakpoint.  The macro itself works and never throws an error, but I have to run it twice, as the first time I run it, it runs the macro to the breakpoint, the second time I run it, it shows me the successfully completed message.

Comment: To add more context, if I run this VBA in the actual VBA editor, I run it twice and it runs.  If I assign this macro to a button, I can run it 1000 times, and it won't do anything.  Per my note above, when running it in the VBA editor , it shows the red dot on the line: :  LastRow = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).  In the VBA Editor, when I run it a second time, it runs the macro and gives me the success message box.  Is there a way to get this to run when assigning to a button though, as I can only get it run in the VBA editor when running it twice and can't with button.

Comment: You have to remove the breakpoint: just click on it.